# Intentionally slow down HttpListener

Tags: c#, web-services, httplistener

I need to simulate a really bad wireless connection from my web server and am using `HttpListener` instead of IIS. Is there any way to intentionally slow down the response? I was thinking of chunking the byte array written to the `OutputStream` and putting a wait timer in between each write, is there a better way?

Comment: You have to throttle network speed through some proxy. Implementing this (slowing down) in the code isn't the right way and it won't exactly simulate slower network speeds. You can find some answers here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/861/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-for-page-load

Comment: I'm testing firmware of a TI wireless chip so most of the answers in that question won't work. A proxy is still a good idea though, I'll see if the firmware can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this to simulate a customer on such a connection I would suggest to use Chrome's developer tools and set the download speed according to your requirements.